# How to make n rows from 1 row with multiple data points in Excel

Tags: excel

I extract data automatically from printed tables into Excel, and generally the solution I use is pretty good. However, because the tables are very complex, it sometimes merges several rows into one due to failed layout recognition.
So, it might look like this (| indicates new cell):

```
Label1|A1|B1|C1
Label2|A2|B2|C2
Label3^Label4|A3^A4|B3^B4|C3^C4
Label5|A5|B5|C5
```

of course, I need 5 rows:

```
Label1|A1|B1|C1
Label2|A2|B2|C2
Label3|A3|B3|C3
Label4|A4|B4|C4
Label5|A5|B5|C5
```

Now, I could do it manually, but: multiply that with tens of thousands of cases... I'm in dire need of an automatable solution - any suggestions?

Comment: You forgot to include the code or method that you use to *extract data automatically from printed tables*

Comment: I use a trial version of a commercial tool and the steps before are unrelated to the issue: that I'm faced with an Excel table with a certain pattern and look for ways to correct it. I have no way to influence the data extraction unless I make myself an expert in AI...

Comment: What you need is do-able (see my answer below).  But maybe, since this is a trial version, they will improve it in the future so this is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some assumptions from your data:

- No duplicates in column 1
- When rows are grouped by this data extractor, each column has the same number of grouped rows, and they are always separated by a `^`
- There are no `^`'s other than those used to separate these grouped rows.

You can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range` or `From within sheet`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

***M Code***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}}),
    
//group by "Column 1"
// This assumes there are no duplicates in Column 1, as shown in your example
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, {
        {"splitRows",(t)=>
            let 
                colNames = Table.ColumnNames(t),
                
            //generate lists of new rows, splitting on the ^
                newRows = List.Generate(
                    ()=>[nr=Text.Split(Table.Column(t, colNames{0}){0}, "^"), idx = 0],
                    each [idx]<List.Count(colNames),
                    each [nr=Text.Split(Table.Column(t, colNames{[idx]+1}){0}, "^"), idx = [idx]+1],
                    each [nr]),
                newTable = Table.FromColumns(newRows,colNames)
            in  
                newTable}
    }),

    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Column1"}),
    #"Expanded splitRows" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "splitRows", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"}, {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"})
in
    #"Expanded splitRows"
```

[image]